# React Displaying List of Items from Ajax request

Tags: ajax, reactjs

I am learning React and I am trying to display a list of users from and ajax call. I am getting an unexpected token error from CodePen when I add the line

```
export default Users;
```

When I remove the line there are no more errors but the list of users is not being displayed.

My code:

```
function GetUsers(project){
  $.ajax({
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            callback(null, data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(data);
            callback(error, {});
        }
    });
}

function UserList(users) {
  const userItems = users.map((user) =>
  <ul>
    <li>
       { user.name }
    </li>
    <li>
      { user.email }
    </li>
    <li>
      { user.phone}
    </li>
  </ul>
 );


 return (userItems);  
}

class Users extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    GetUsers(null, function (err, data) {
      if (err)
      {
        console.log(err); 
      }// do something
      this.setState({ users: data })
    }.bind(this))
  }

  render() {
    return(
        <UserList user = {this.state.users} />
      );
  }

}


if (document.getElementById('root')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Users />, document.getElementById('root'));
}
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JvWJqj) is my code.

Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: Code provided doesn't work.

Comment: @DanielD Correct I am trying to get the code to display a list of users from the ajax request.

Comment: you can't export in CodePen... why do you need to `export`?

Comment: @TylerSebastian I am unfamiliar with CodePen. thank you, I'm updating the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem 1 in AJAX call

```
function GetUsers(project){
  $.ajax({
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            callback(null, data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(data);
            callback(error, {});
        }
    });
}
```

`$.ajax` is asynchronous call, that means it doesn't returns directly any value (how it could if it is fetching the results from the internet) it Just creates another function which will call `success` and `error` when completed.

That's why we need to wrap it with callbacks

```
function GetUsers(project, resolve = () => {}, reject = () => {}) {
}
```

## Problem 2 in mount

```
  componentDidMount() {
    GetUsers(null, function (err, data) {
      if (err)
      {
        console.log(err); 
      }// do something
      this.setState({ users: data })
    }.bind(this))
  }
```

This code is completely wrong, it has even syntax error so not worth to discuss it in details.

We need to call our new function and pass success callback for mutating the state

```
GetUsers(null, users => {
  this.setState({ users });
});
```

In this way we will call `GetUsers` wait for it's results and only after that we will mutate the state with new result

## 3 problem in component creation

React component's don't have state by default, you need to infer the state from constructor so we need to change initialization to

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      users: false
    };
  }
```

otherwise you will get `Cannot call setState of undefined` as state is not automatically created for performance purposes and all components are Pure by default.

I have created a working sandbox here

[image: Edit m78ryj51zy]

Answer (score 0):

in

```
function GetUsers(project){
  $.ajax({
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
        success: function (data) {
            return data;
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return {};
        }
    });
}
```

--

```
success: function (data) {
    return data;
}
```

doesn't do what you think it does. `return data` isn't really returning the data... anywhere.

You need to have a callback.

```
function GetUsers(project, callback){
  $.ajax({
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
        success: function (data) {
            callback(null, data)
        },
        error: function (error) {
            callback(error, {})
        }
    });
}

class Users extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    GetUsers(null, function (err, data) {
      if (err) // do something
      this.setState({ users: data })
    }.bind(this))
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <UserList user = {this.state.users} />
    );
  }
}
```

you can also `Promise`-ify things to simplify the logic